# Convert a SELECT statement into its corresponding UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query that counts the exact population whose information I need to update using an UPDATE statement. But it contains some complex joins and I'm not sure how to recreate that statement in an UPDATE statement. Any help?

My query is here:

```
select distinct c.id
from implementation.tt_ngma_exclude_emails nee
join customer c on nee.util_account_id = c.util_internal_id
join customer_notification_contact cnc on cnc.customer_id = c.id
left join customer_notification_contact_audit cnca on cnca.customer_id = c.id
where cnc.changed_on = '2015-11-15 12:30:02';
```

The goal here is to update a specific field in the `customer_notification_contact` table, not the implementation table I selected from. I want to set the `email` field in the cnc table to NULL everywhere that cnc.customer_id = c.id

Here's my attempt but it doesn't seem to work:

```
UPDATE customer_notification_contact cnc
(select distinct cnc.customer_id opower_customer_id
from implementation.tt_ngma_exclude_emails nee
join customer c on nee.util_account_id = c.util_internal_id
join customer_notification_contact cnc on cnc.customer_id = c.id
where cnc.changed_on = '2015-11-15 12:30:02'
) T2
SET cnc.email = NULL
WHERE cnc.customer_id = T2.opower_customer_id;
```

Comment: the joins would stay the same. just change `select ... from ... ` to `update ...`

Comment: Sorry I think the original question was vague. I want to UPDATE customer_notification_contact. Not implementation.tt_ngma_exclude_emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please give this a try just replace `T1.SOME_COLUMN` (2nd last line) with your actual column name that you want to update.  I added GROUP BY CNC.CUSTOMER_ID because when you're updating multiple rows you should know which customer the count belongs to.  unless you're trying to update all rows with the same count which i am assuming you're not trying to do.

```
UPDATE customer_notification_contact T1,
(
select count(distinct c.id) AS MY_COUNT,CNC.CUSTOMER_ID
from implementation.tt_ngma_exclude_emails nee
join customer c on nee.util_account_id = c.util_internal_id
join customer_notification_contact cnc on cnc.customer_id = c.id
left join customer_notification_contact_audit cnca on cnca.customer_id = c.id
where cnc.changed_on = '2015-11-15 12:30:02'
GROUP BY CNC.CUSTOMER_ID
)T2
SET T1.SOME_COLUMN = T2.MY_COUNT
WHERE T1.CUSTOMER_ID = T2.CUSTOMER_ID
```

**UPDATE** after seeing updated question this should be the query.

```
UPDATE customer_notification_contact T1,
(
select distinct c.id
  from implementation.tt_ngma_exclude_emails nee
  join customer c on nee.util_account_id = c.util_internal_id
  join customer_notification_contact cnc on cnc.customer_id = c.id
  left join customer_notification_contact_audit cnca on cnca.customer_id = c.id
  where cnc.changed_on = '2015-11-15 12:30:02'
)T2
SET T1.EMAIL = NULL
WHERE T1.CUSTOMER_ID = T2.id
```

Comment: I think this is really close to what I need. I've updated my question to be a little more clear.

Comment: then try adding `,T1.email = NULL` to the end of the 2nd last line after you change the T2 subquery like how you have it..you can do it

Comment: Syntax error: '(
select distinct c.id
  from implementation.tt_ngma_exclude_emails nee
  join c' at line 2

Comment: i updated my answer it needs a comma between T1 and T2